# ClassNotFoundException when lib invokes app class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, classnotfoundexception

I have an JavaEE project on Glassfish with name TestApp.
TestApp have a class a.b.c.D

TestApp uses a library testlib.
In testlib  have a method test() where occur invocation of a.b.c.D TestApp's class, such as

```
public String test() throws Exception {
    Class c = Class.forName("a.b.c.D");
    return c.newInstance().toString();
}
```

Why Class.forName("a.b.c.D") throws ClassNotFoundException when test() invoked from TestApp?

But if I create new library testlib2 and put a.b.c.D class in it, and add this library to TestApp, then Class.forName("a.b.c.D") works normally

Comment: How is this deployed? Is `testlib` in some classloader which the app can see, but which can't see the app? That sounds like a fairly likely explanation...

Comment: App deployed from GF web console. I don't have information about classloaders. In my code classloaders not created. All by default

Comment: Well there will still *be* classloaders... I suggest you log info about them in both your app and the library, and that will helo you understand what's going in.

Comment: Thank you. `TestApp` using `WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)` and `testlib` using `EarLibClassLoader : urlSet = [URLEntry : file:/home/shurik2533/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/TestApp/lib/testlib.jar, URLEntry : file:/home/shurik2533/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/TestApp/lib/testlibA.jar] doneCalled = false`